# Equivalence of Frankl's Conjecture

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, conjectures, universal-algebra

Frankl’s conjecture is one of the most famous problems in combinatorics. Frankl's conjecture claims: For every finite non-empty set $A$ and for every Frankl's family $F$ on $A$ exists $a\in A$ such that $$|\{X\in F | a\in X \}|\geqslant \frac{|F|}{2}.$$
How can be proved that Frankl's conjecture is equivalent to next statement:
For every finite lattice L exists $a \in\mathcal{M}(L),$ such that $|a\downarrow|\leqslant \frac{|L|}{2},$ where $\mathcal{M}(L)$ is the set of all strictly $\wedge-$irreducible elements of L and $a ↓ = \{b ∈ L | b ≤ a\}?$

Comment: You can find the proof in this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316592900686?via%3Dihub)

Comment: @Eran There is a proof for semi-lattice and I didn't udnerstand it well. How it would go for lattices?